# How to set the resolution permanently?

Tags: fonts

I'm new to Mathematica, each time I start Mathematica, I have to enter

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, FontProperties -> {"ScreenResolution" -> Automatic}]
```

to set the resolution, or else the font would be very tiny.

How can I set it permanently? I'm using Mathematica 10.0.1 on Windows 7, some of the post are Mac related -- the menu is a little bit different, which confused me.

BTW.: With this website 
http://dpi.lv/
you can check the screen resolution and ppi very quickly, very handy.

Comment: Simply changing `$FrontEndSession` to `$FrontEnd` in your code will do it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you!