# Front End options

Tags: front-end, options, system

Inspired by [a recent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72980/121) and others like it, and not finding an existing duplicate, I ask:

- **What is the hierarchy of Front End options?**
- **How do they work?**
- **How can their values be set and recalled?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Option hierarchy

[Quoting](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7747447) John Fultz:

> Options work on an inheritance model.  ...  It all
>   starts someplace.  That would be the hard-coded option values in the
>   front end C code.  The root of the inheritance of options.  Then one
>   typically thinks of `$FrontEnd` as being the next level down, but
>   there's another level in between.  That is `$DefaultFrontEnd`. So, at
>   the global level, it's  -> `$DefaultFrontEnd` ->
>   `$FrontEnd` -> `$FrontEndSession`.  But only values set to `$FrontEnd`
>   get written to your preferences file.

In addition to these global settings many Front End options (or their equivalents) can be set at the Notebook level, with e.g. `EvaluationNotebook[]`, and these, when set, take local priority.

Settings made to the Notebook are saved in the Notebook (`.nb`).  Settings made to `$FrontEnd` are saved in:

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "FrontEnd", "init.m"}]
```

Settings to either `$FrontEndSession` or `$DefaultFrontEnd` do not persist between sessions.  Settings made to `$FrontEndSession` override those to `$FrontEnd` for the duration of the session, while `$DefaultFrontEnd` are only used if the same option is specified nowhere else.

### Setting and recalling option values

`$FrontEnd` and Notebook options can be set and cleared using the [Option Inspector](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionInspector.html) with the menu selections **Global Preferences** and **Selected Notebook** respectively.  To clear an option click the **x** next to its option name:

[image]

Options can be set and recalled at all levels with [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html) and [`Options`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options.html).
For example one could make the following settings:

```
SetOptions[$DefaultFrontEnd,     FontColor -> Red    ]

SetOptions[$FrontEnd,            FontColor -> Orange ]

SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,     FontColor -> Magenta]

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], FontColor -> Blue   ]
```

Many options are aslo accessible and configurable through [`CurrentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentValue.html).  An unqualified `CurrentValue` will show the value lowest in the hierarchy (with the highest priority):

```
CurrentValue[FontColor] // InputForm
```

> ```
> RGBColor[0, 0, 1]  (* blue *)
> ```

A qualified `CurrentValue` will show the other settings as well:

```
CurrentValue[#, FontColor] & /@
  {$DefaultFrontEnd, $FrontEnd, $FrontEndSession} // InputForm
```

> ```
> {RGBColor[1, 0, 0],    (* red     *)
>  RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0],  (* orange  *)
>  RGBColor[1, 0, 1]}    (* magenta *)
> ```

The qualified form may be used to set option values:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], FontColor] = Green;
```

If the Notebook option is cleared through the **Option Inspector**, or a new Notebook is opened, the next setting up the hierarchy is used:

```
CurrentValue[FontColor] // InputForm
```

> ```
> RGBColor[1, 0, 1]
> ```

After *Mathematica* is restarted the `$FrontEnd` setting persists:

```
CurrentValue[FontColor] // InputForm
```

> ```
> RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0]
> ```

---

As [David Creech](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1387/david-creech) noted in a comment it is possible to use [`Inherited`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inherited.html) as an option value to un-set that option and revert to the next higher level of the hierarchy.  Example:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], FontColor -> Blue]

Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

> {FontColor -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1], FrontEndVersion -> . . .}

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], FontColor -> Inherited]

Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

> {FrontEndVersion -> "10.1 for Microsoft Windows . . .}

Note that the Option has been entirely removed from the Notebook options list.

Comment: I hope to make this answer a worthwhile reference.  Please let me know of any corrections that are needed and offer any suggestions for improvement or extension that you have.

Comment: You could cover the use of Inherited to unset an option without using the Option Inspector.

Comment: @David Nice suggestion; thank you!

Comment: Where `Stylesheets` come into play?

Comment: @ercegovac they come after the settings on the `NotebookObject`, but before those set at the `Cell` level. Essentially you have ``$FrontEnd > $FrontEndSession | $DefaultFrontEnd > NotebookObject > Cell Style (StyleSheet)  >  Box Form (e.g. BoxData, TextData) > CellObject  > BoxObject``.

Answer (score 4):

A useful point on recalling style definitions. These may be queried at the stylesheet level using `StyleDefinitions`:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {StyleDefinitions, "Input", FontColor}]

Automatic
```

They cannot, however, be set so easily (but I've got code to do that e.g. [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/9f817b58033db5ef00ee15f3ee382264ed86e7d4/Packages/StylesheetEdits.m#L950)):

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {StyleDefinitions, "Input", 
   FontColor}] = Red

Automatic
```

One useful thing about this is we can inspect more interesting options programmatically using this:

```
inspectBoxOptions[element_] :=

 With[{boxo = 
    StringTrim[
      StringReplace[SymbolName[element], "Framed" -> "Frame"], 
      "Box"] <> "BoxOptions"},
  CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {StyleDefinitions, "Input", boxo}] /.

      s_Symbol?(StringStartsQ[SymbolName[#], boxo] &) :> 
    StringTrim[SymbolName[s], boxo]
  ]

inspectBoxOptions@Checkbox

{"BaseStyle" -> {}, "DefaultBaseStyle" -> "Checkbox", 
 "Enabled" -> Automatic, 
 "Appearance" -> {Automatic, None, "Normal", Automatic}, 
 "Background" -> Automatic, "ImageSize" -> All, 
 "ImageMargins" -> Automatic, "FrameMargins" -> Automatic, 
 "ContentPadding" -> True, "BaselinePosition" -> Automatic, 
 "Alignment" -> {Automatic, Automatic}, "AutoAction" -> False, 
 "ContinuousAction" -> False, "Momentary" -> False}
```