# Can I modify Ctrl-- to insert Indexed expressions?

Tags: front-end, keyboard

For me, `Indexed[x, n]` is a much more useful and versatile construct than `Subscript[x, n]`. I would therefore like to modify `Ctrl--` to insert `Indexed` expressions instead of `Subscript`s. Is this possible?

Note that I do, occasionally, need to work with code containing `Subscript`s, so simply redefining `Subscript[x__] := Indexed[x]` is not an option for me.

Comment: May I ask, why do you prefer one to another? Where do you used such indexed expressions: in Input cells? In DisplayFormula cells? Somewhere else? What is the advantage?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I use them in input cells, primarily as a substitute for `Part`'s ugly double-bracket notation. They're also useful for integration over multidimensional regions, e.g., `Integrate[Indexed[x, 1]^2 Indexed[x, 2]^2, Element[x, Rectangle[]]]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This my question is to the whole community, by I just directed it to Mr.Wizard to address one. Previously it was known that Mma "does not like" to operate with expressions with subscripts. It was a general knowledge that it may occasionally evaluate an expression containing subscribed variables correctly, but may also return a mistake. So we preferred to use, say, `x1 `, rather than `Subscript[x,1] `. The question is, if this is not a problem for calculations with indexed variables, as OP states?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Could I ask you for an example of Mathematica giving incorrect results in computations with `Subscript`s? I've never run into any such problems with either `Subscript` or `Indexed`, but my use cases of both are admittedly limited.

Comment: I never tried anything with Indexed before, in fact I did not know about its existence until now. So this I cannot. With Indexed, however, I and other people tried many times. When I started with Mma3 it was simply a "no go". It seemed that in the last versions (9 and 10) it is not the case, but I recently tried to make calculations in the 10.0.2 with the subscripts and it, indeed, made several operations correctly, but then returned an erroneous result which immediately turns into the right one, as soon as I removed the subscripts. I did not save this example though.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Do you remember what kind of operations you were doing when you ran into these problems? I would very much like to know where the use of `Subscript`s can cause problems.

Comment: No, I cannot tell. I just took a note that it is dangerous to use subscribed variables. You see, you never know, if it would not fail you in operations that you did not try yet. However, I think this discussion might be useful, if we place it as a regular question. Then the whole community will answer, and somebody has already tried these possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a **Palette**:

```
CreatePalette @ PasteButton @ Indexed[\[SelectionPlaceholder], \[Placeholder]]
```

Or an **Input Alias**:

```
AppendTo[
 CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, "InputAliases"],
 "idx" -> TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, "IndexedDefault"]
]
```

For a system-wide keyboard shortcut you can copy `KeyEventTranslations.tr` from `SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\(your OS)` within `$InstallationDirectory` to the like path within `$UserBaseDirectory` and replace the line containing `"KeypadSubtract"` with:

```
Item[KeyEvent["KeypadSubtract", Modifiers -> {Control}],
    FrontEndExecute[{
        FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
            TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, "IndexedDefault"], After]
    }]],
```

This will allow insertion of the same template as above.  I am still seeking a way to emulate the default Subscript behavior where a template is inserted for a blank line, but the first element is auto-filled if an expression exists.

---

With the hint from [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) to use [`NotebookApply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookApply.html) we can get nearly perfect emulation with:

```
Item[KeyEvent["KeypadSubtract", Modifiers -> {Control}],
    FrontEndExecute[{
        FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], All, Word];
        FrontEnd`NotebookApply[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
          TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, "IndexedDefault"]]
    }]
],
```

Related:

- [Preventing Superscript from being interpreted as Power when using Ctrl+^ shortcut?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33672/121)

Comment: @David The first snippet creates a Palette Notebook -- look for a small window with a button; on my system it appears in the upper right hand corner.  Yes, it should be possible to map this to a key combination, however (1) I need to modify my configuration to test it, and (2) I was trying to think of a way to emulate the (default) behavior with Subscript, rather than inserting the double placeholder object.  I shall update this answer later with whatever I can get working.

Comment: @David Please see update

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You can use this: `SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Character];
SelectionMove[nb, All, Character];
NotebookApply[nb, 
 TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, 
  "IndexedDefault"]]`

Comment: @Kuba Thanks!  `NotebookApply` is what I needed.  However I get better behavior from `All, Word` as shown in the present answer; can you confirm?

Comment: @Kuba This is fantastic! I'm surprised you found a way to emulate the selection behavior of `Subscript`. I have, however, noticed something strange: while I can override `KeypadSubtract` and `_` just fine, I can't seem to modify the behavior of `-`. Is this intended?

Comment: Sure, `Word` makes more sense. @DavidZhang I haven't tested it, usually I was using key that are not occupied. (*deleting old comments.

Comment: @David I think it is because `-` is bound in the menus and you would need to override them as well; replacing "KeypadSubtract" seemed simpler and equally effective.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what it seems me you would like to is to use the `InputAliases` function by evaluating in your notebook the following expression:

```
 SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
 InputAliases -> {"ind" -> 
    "Evaluate[Indexed[\[SelectionPlaceholder],\[Placeholder]]]"}]
```

After that as soon as you type Esc+ind+Esc placeholders to type in an indexed expression will appear in the place of the cursor.

This is, however, boring, since you will need to evaluate such an operation in each notebook before its use.

One may also do it once for ever as follows:

1. Having any of your notebooks open go to Menu/Format/OptionInspector (alternatively press Shift+Ctrl+O). This opens the OptionInspector.
2. In its slot entitled "Show option values" choose Global Options.
3. In the slot "Lookup" type InputAlaises, or alternatively in the left window choose Edit Options
4. In the right window choose InputAlaises and click on the gray box at the right margin of the line.
5. This opens a dialog box with a list of the already existing aliases. Press the button "Add".
6. This opens the "Edit setting rules" dialog box enabling one to introduce a new rule. By default x->y stays there.
7. Remove x and insert the key combination that you need, say, in. (do not put simply i, since such an aliase already exists, I checked).
8. Instead of y insert `TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", 
   "\[Placeholder]"}, "IndexedDefault"]`. Click the "OK" button on the both dialog windows, and "Apply" on top of the OptionInspector window.

Done. Now as soon as you type anywhere in any of your notebooks Esc+in+Esc you will get the placeholders enabling you to type in the expression which will appear to be indexed.

Have fun!

Comment: One can add a persistent input alias far more easily; simply evaluate `AppendTo[
 CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "InputAliases"],
 "idx" -> TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, "IndexedDefault"]
]`.  For more information see:  [(72989)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72989/121)